# Copy Paste on a mac

Tags: mac, clipboard

I have installed on my mac Ubuntu with VirtualBox. I would like to copy informations displayed on a terminal and then paste it on a 'edit-file' on my mac or wherever on my mac. It doesn't seems to work. I highlighted some lines with on the terminal, command-right clicked and then copied the content, but I can paste it wherever on ubuntu but not on a common file on my mac.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you have guest additions installed?

Comment: I am really new to Ubuntu, what do you mean by 'guest additions'

Comment: Take a look at [Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

Comment: Finally, I read the doc and I installed the 'Guest additions' but nothing change as for my copy-paste...

Answer (score 0):

You can always type any command followed by >file_name.txt, then you will have written all the terminal info into disk.

For example:

```
root@ubuntu:/# ls -a >anyfolder.txt
root@ubuntu:/# gedit anyfolder.txt
```